# How to pass string with no quotes as a parameter in function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, tastypie

If my api takes the query as http://localhost:8000/api/v1/rental/?place__startswith=kathmandu then how can i do generic search in reactjs. What i tried is i passed the default parameter as search(query=kathmandu) so that the result of place named kathmandu will be listed by default and when user types place name that they want to search then it should display those places instead of kathmndu. But i am getting an error saying Uncaught ReferenceError: kathmandu is not defined. How can i resolve this problem?

```
componentWillMount(){
        this.search();
      }

search(query=kathmandu){
    let url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/rental/?place__startswith=query';
    Request.get(url).then((response) => {
        console.log('response',response.body.objects);
        this.setState({
            place:response.body.objects
        });
    });
  }

  searchUpdated(term){
    console.log('term is',term);
    this.search(term);
  }

  render() {
        var margin = { marginTop : '13em' }; 
        let location = _.map(this.state.place, (place) => {
            return(
                    <div className="searchResult">
                        <li>{place.place}</li>
                        <li>{place.city}</li>
                    </div>
                )
        });
        return(
            <div className = "container">
                <div className="content text-align-center">
                    <div className="row text-xs-center">
                        <div className="middle-text"  style={margin}>
                            <h1 className="welcome"><span>Welcome </span></h1>
                            <button ref="test" className="btn how-it-works" onClick={this.handleClick}>Search Space</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="mySearch" className="overlay"  onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}>
                  <button className="btn closebtn" onClick={this.handleClick}>x</button>
                  <div className="overlay-content">
                        <SearchInput ref="searchInput" className="search-input" onChange={this.searchUpdated} />
                        <ul>{location}</ul>
                  </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `search(query=kathmandu){` be `search(query="kathmandu"){`?

Comment: Thats what not working to me as my api takes the url query in the format  http://localhost:8000/api/v1/rental/?place__startswith=kathmandu instead of  http://localhost:8000/api/v1/rental/?place__startswith='kathmandu'

Comment: Why am i getting down vote ?

Comment: Inside your API you need to strip the quotes, as if you pass param without quotes, it will be treated as a variable, hence the reference error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

```
search( query='kathmandu' ){
```

And:

`let url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/rental/?place__startswith=' + encodeURIComponent(query);`

NB as your query string actually does only contains letter, you don't need `encodeURIComponent` for that example, but you might need it in other cases.

Comment: I get empty response doing this.

Comment: Passing parameter doesnot work, not even encodeURIComponent('"kathmandu"'). but this works. componentWillMount(){
   this.search();
  }

  search(){
   let url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/rental/?place__startswith=kathmandu';
   Request.get(url).then((response) => {
    console.log('response',response.body.objects);
    this.setState({
     place:response.body.objects
    });
   });
  }

  searchUpdated(term){
   console.log('term is',term);
   this.search();
  }

Comment: I meant that I forgot the enclosing quotes around the place `'"kathmandu"'` and not `"kathmandu"`, did you add them ?

Comment: And `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/rental/?place__startswith=%27kathmandu%27` is working ? NB if yes, see update to answer.

Comment: And if it's `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/rental/?place__startswith=kathmandu` you're looking for, it's just `query="kathmandu"`

Comment: sorry that way it returns empty objects.